# Joomla Redirect Manager does not work?

Tags: redirect, joomla, duplicates, content-management-system, robots.txt

I just found the Joomla Redirect Manager. 
Tried to redirect this URL

[http://www.eldvigateli.com/електродвигатели-елин/новини-електродвигатели/334-смяна-лагери](http://www.eldvigateli.com/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8/334-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8)

to this:

[http://www.eldvigateli.com/услуги/механични-ремонти/смяна-лагери](http://www.eldvigateli.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8)

But nothing happened.

I tried also with any other URL, but nothing is working.

Any possible reasons/solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common misunderstanding about the Joomla Redirect Manager is that it redirects one link to another. In fact, the Redirect Manager redirects a 404 link to another, valid link. We have explained everything about it here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-joomlas-redirect-manager-system-plugin-works

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an URL 'not correctly redirected' so said Google Search Console.

When trying to redirect my URL, I experienced the same problem described above with 'Joomla Redirect Manager' ( and I read the explanation by itoctopus).

But I managed to use 'Joomla Redirect Manager', simply by using in 'Expired URL' the URL without the domain name, for example: /component/jcomments/, in New URL I use a full URL with the domain name.

Now all is working fine in my case using 'Joomla Redirect Manager'

In the case described above, try that in **'Joomla Redirect Manager'**:

**'Expired URL'**:/електродвигатели-елин/новини-електродвигатели/334-смяна-лагери

**'New URL'**:[http://www.eldvigateli.com/услуги/механични-ремонти/смяна-лагери](http://www.eldvigateli.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8)

Comment: Hi Borox, thank you for giving an answer to this question. To help others searching for answers to the same topic could you improve it by providing a bit more detail as to how you resolved the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for tips to improving an answer.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your suggestions, I modified the answer